# When should I use pointer or reference members, and when should I pass nullptr or this as parent pointer in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, reference

### The Code

I've been writing this c++ with Qt knowing it works but not really understanding why I sometimes do things other than "I just know I should be doing this".

This is my startup class which initialises my classes:

```
namespace GUI
{
    Startup::Startup() :
        QObject(nullptr),
        m_setupTab(*new SetupTab(nullptr)),
        m_regTab(*new CbcRegistersTab(nullptr)),
        m_dataTab(*new DataTestTab(nullptr)),

        m_mainView(*new MainView(nullptr,
                                 m_setupTab,
                                 m_regTab,
                                 m_dataTab)),

        m_systemController(*new SystemController(nullptr,
                                                 Provider::getSettingsAsSingleton())),

        m_dataTest(*new DataTest(nullptr,
                                m_systemController)),

        m_setupTabVm(new SetupTabViewManager(this,
                                             m_setupTab,
                                             m_systemController,
                                             Provider::getSettingsAsSingleton() ))

    {

    }
```

Then in my header file the member variables are described as such:

```
private:
    SetupTab& m_setupTab;
    CbcRegistersTab& m_regTab;
    DataTestTab& m_dataTab;

    MainView& m_mainView;
    Settings* m_settings;

    SystemController& m_systemController;

    DataTest& m_dataTest;

    SetupTabViewManager* m_setupTabVm;
```

The main difference between the view manager and everything else is that view manager passes signals between the tab classes and everything else.

Then to start this in my main, all I do is this:

```
    GUI::Startup startup;
    startup.show();


SetupTabViewManager.cpp:

#include "setuptabviewmanager.h"
#include "View/setuptab.h"
#include "Model/systemcontroller.h"
#include "Model/settings.h"
#include <QDebug>

namespace GUI
{
    SetupTabViewManager::SetupTabViewManager(QObject *parent,
                                             SetupTab& tab,
                                             SystemController& sysCtrl,
                                             Settings& config) :
        QObject(parent),
        m_setupTab(tab),
        m_systemController(sysCtrl)
    {
        WireMessages(config);
        WireSetupTabButtons(config);
    }

    void SetupTabViewManager::WireMessages(Settings& config)
    {
        connect(&config, SIGNAL(notifyStatusMessage(QString)), //for QT4
                &m_setupTab, SLOT(onStatusUpdate(QString)) );

        connect(&m_systemController, SIGNAL(notifyStatusMessage(QString)),
                &m_setupTab, SLOT(onStatusUpdate(QString)));
    }

    void SetupTabViewManager::WireSetupTabButtons(Settings& config)
    {
        connect(&m_setupTab, SIGNAL(onBtnLoadSettingsClicked(bool)),
                &config, SLOT(onLoadButtonClicked(bool)) );

        connect(&config, SIGNAL(setHwTree(QStandardItemModel*)),
                &m_setupTab, SLOT(setHwTreeView(QStandardItemModel*)));

        connect(&m_setupTab, SIGNAL(onBtnInitClicked()),
                &m_systemController, SLOT(startInitialiseHw()));

        connect(&m_setupTab, SIGNAL(onBtnCfgClicked()),
                &m_systemController, SLOT(startConfigureHw()));

    }
}
```

### Questions

What is the advantage of initialising a class in a member variable as a pointer or a reference? I just know when I make a "view manager", I should initialise the member variable as a pointer. Though I'm not sure why?

Also what is the advantage of "this" or "nullptr" as the parent to the class?

Comment: This is specific to how Qt and QObject handles memory. I'm not an expert in it, but squinting at it, it looks like you are leaking almost all of your objects (the ones that you pass `nullptr` into). You should get advice from somebody that's well versed in Qt :)

Comment: In qt if you declare the parent you can perform automatic operations: i.e. if you destroy an object with some children, these one are deleted automatically.

Comment: So why for instance in QT would I want the view manager to pass "this" and in everything else I pass "nullptr" ? It's never really been explained to me the difference between the two

Comment: I have never used Qt but what you are doing here looks pretty unorthodox. Are you working from a reference?

Comment: You mean how I start the startup class? I added the code in if that's what you meant. I actually based this on a course I took for QT - though it was never really explained why the above was best practise.

Comment: See [object trees and ownership](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/objecttrees.html). In some cases it could be that you set the parent elswhere in your code. For example you pass `m_systemController` to the `SetupTabViewManager`. Maybe somewhere in your code `m_setupTabVm` takes ownership of `m_systemController`. It's really hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: I added the SetupTabViewManager - it doesn't take ownership. Should I be passing this differently? (I'm still learning - had to quickly produce this piece of QT with very little experience)

Comment: Thankyou everyone - after doing some more reading I now understand it much better. I've changed everything apart from the actual QObjects themselves to pass "this" which makes much more sense to me now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt objects are organized in object trees. It allows a programmer not to care about destructing the created objects: they will be deleted automatically when their respective parents are deleted.

If you take a look at almost any Qt GUI application, then you will see that all of its widgets (buttons, checkboxes, panels, etc.) have one single ancestor - the main window. When you delete the main window, all your application widgets are automatically deleted.

You can set up this parent-child relation by passing a parent object to a newly created child:

```
QWidget *mainWidget = ...
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton(mainWidget);
```

In this case, `btn` object becomes a child of the `mainWidget` object, and from this moment you may not delete that child manually.

If you create an object without a parent, you should always delete it by yourself.

As **thuga** mentioned in the comments, you can transfer object ownership later. Widgets can be places inside layouts and it will make them children of the layout owner. Or you can even explicitly set parent with `QObject::setParent`.

And as for declaring class members as pointers or references - it does not really matter. It's just a question of convenience.

Comment: Thankyou - that's what I wanted clearing up. I guess the tutorials were just showing us two different ways to do things.

Comment: As far as I can make out, the OP has posted some really broken code. (The whole `*new SomethingSomething(nullptr)`-pattern) Can you comment on this? Should he not pass `this` to those objects?

Comment: That was my next question as to why the tutorials made me do this. Though this code is working - I have a util function which tells me when things are destroyed - and everything is deleted when I want them to be.

Comment: *If you create an object without a parent, you should always delete it by yourself.* This is not always the case. Ownership can be transferred in many different ways. For example, adding a widget to a layout will automatically reparent the widget.

Comment: @Magnus Hoff it is completely legal to pass a null pointer as a parent for a Qt object. In this case you just lose the advantage of autamatic object delettion. I can't tell about the posted code for sure, because I don't see the whole picture, but _it seems_ that he actually should pass `this` everywhere.

Comment: Hmmm I didn't realise you lost automatic deletion. But I guess that makes sense now I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt world all child objects are getting deleted when their parent object is deleting. If you do not define class members (`QObjects`) as pointers, they will be deleted twice: once by their parent, and second time when your class object is destructed by itself, and this can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Right - so what is the advantage of declaring the member variable as a pointer or a reference - or is there none?

Comment: They will be destroyed twice only if their parent is destroyed first.

Comment: @thuga, that is what usually happen.

Comment: I find that to be the case very rarely. If you use automatic variables, then usually children are member variables of the parent, and in that case it won't happen.